# get_query_var() not working in pre_get_posts

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wp-query, hooks

I'm using the `pre_get_posts` hook to order the main query on all my custom post type / taxonomy pages using a custom meta value. As part of the logic, I am trying to determine which taxonomy is currently being displayed by using `get_query_var('taxonomy')`, however no matter what I try, it keeps returning a blank string:

```
function sort_query($query)
    ...
    if (is_tax()){
        ...
        echo get_query_var('taxonomy'); // Empty
        echo get_query_var($query->query_vars['taxonomy']); // Empty
        ...
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'sort_query');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated; thanks!

Comment: Are you sure `is_tax` is working and what you want to use?

Comment: @Wyck As far as I can tell based on limited testing it is working as expected; however I am open to alternatives. Basically need a way to capture the tax and apply different ordering based on it.

Comment: I am also struggling with a similar situation. Some plugin is executing query_posts() but when that query hits my pre_get_posts action, global $wp_query and $q parameter are different. get_query_var check $wp_query and returns empty. Looking at query_posts() source, it unsets and re-sets $wp_query, so how can $wp_query stay something old in my action?

Comment: Just a pro-tip - don't use global template tags in a `pre_get_posts` hook - use the method of the query instance i.e. `$query->is_tax()`

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this?

```
function sort_query($query)
    if ($query->is_tax() && $query->is_main_query()){
        echo $query->query_vars['taxonomy']; 
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'post_title' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
        //do other stuff
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'sort_query');
```

Happy Coding,

Kuchenundkakao

Comment: As AcidX suggested, try `$query->tax_query->queries[0]['taxonomy']` - no matter what the query args where, `WP_Query` will always parse them into a tax query, so this should be a surefire way to get the (primary) taxonomy that was queried.